# quiero mostrar y ocultar la contraseña pero tengo 3 botones que llaman a al mismo metodo como diferenciar cada boton

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs

```
        <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
        <b-form @submit.prevent>
          <b-row align-h="between">
            <b-col xl="4" class="form-group">
              <!--Input de la contraseña actual-->
              <h2 class="primary h3 pt-2">{{ $t("changePassword.userData") }}</h2>
              <b-row class="mt-2">
                <b-col cols="12">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    :name="$t('changePassword.fieldPassword')"
                    rules="required|alpha_dash|min:6"
                    v-slot="{ classes, errors }"
                  >
                    <b-form-group
                      v-bind:label="$t('changePassword.labelPassword')"
                      label-for="password"
                    >
                      <b-input-group size="sm">
                        <template v-slot:append>
                          <b-input-group-text>
                            <i
                              class="icon-view mr-0"
                              v-bind:title="
                            $t('changePassword.buttonShowPassword')"
            @click="showPassword(userCred.passwordType)"
                            ></i>
                          </b-input-group-text>
                        </template>
                        <b-form-input
                          id="password"
                          name="loginPassword"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          :type="userCred.passwordType"
                          :class="classes"
                          v-model="userCred.passwordCurrent"
                        />
                      </b-input-group>
                      <span class="is-invalid-text">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                    </b-form-group>
                  </ValidationProvider>
```

tengo tres input con lo mimso datos esto es para colocar uno la contraseña anterior uno la contraseña nueva y la otra es para confirmar la contraseña nueva necesito mostrar y ocultar la contraseña pero se me muestran las tres si presiono cualquiera de ellos como hago para identificar cada uno de los botones pero ejecute el mismo metodo
Mi metodo es este siempre tengo que pasar el mismo parametro debidoqye es para que se muestre la contraseña y realize el mostrar y ocultar

```
             methods: {
               showPassword(passwordType) {
               this.userCred.passwordType =
                 passwordType === "password" ? "text" : "password";
             },
           }
```

como hago para identificar cada boton y pasar el mismo parametro pero que solo muestre el que estoy seleccionando y no todos

Comment: yo veo un solo input.. probaste con un v-if?

Comment: para poder publicar me decia que era mucho codigo asi que coloque solo uno, pero es el mismo solo que tres veces y lo unico que cambias es el v-model

Comment: Pon ese ejemplo y porque no te funciona un v-if?

Comment: pero el v-if en donde lo coloco porque si lo coloco en donde esta el icono lo oculta

Comment: En los input que quieras ocultar...

Comment: mostrar y ocultar el password

Comment: Creo que te estoy diciendo algo, pero por que estoy confundido.. tu problema es como mostrar y ocultar algo, o como pasar parametros a una funcion?